# What is the algorithm behind GROUP USING 'collected' and 'merge'

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Pig [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#group) says if some conditions are met(these conditions are described in doc), Pig can do map side `GROUP`. Can someone explain this algorithm? I want to get a deep understanding of what can be done by MapReduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, imagine the file below:

```
10 - 1
14 - 2
10 - 3
12 - 4
12 - 5
20 - 6
21 - 7
17 - 8
12 - 9
17 - 10
```

Then, the load is going to store your file, like this (imagine your cluster have 3 nodes -  If you use a Identity Map-Reduce Job than you can achieve the same result setting the reduce number to 3. If your file is skweed you can have some performance problems). 
The loader used for this must guarantee that it does not split a single value of a key across multiple splits. (http://wiki.apache.org/pig/MapSideCogroup)

```
part-r-00000  part-r-00001   part-r-00002
10 - 1        14 - 2         20 - 6
10 - 3        17 - 8         21 - 7
12 - 4        17 - 10
12 - 9
```

Now, hadoop framework is going to spawns one map task for each partition generated. I this case 3 map-tasks.
So imagine that you are going to sum the second field, that process can run just in the map side.

```
part-m-00000
10 - 17
12 - 13

part-m-00001
14 - 2
17 - 18

part-m-00002
20 - 13
```

In the case of COGROUP, i imagine that is goind to execute in a similiar way. Each map-task is going to operate in two partitions file with the same keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the source code for the algorithm. A one liner answer is that both implement a merge algorithm (i.e. data has to be sorted by group key in advanced so that (a) sorting is not required and (b) by iterating over the data you can find where the group key changes.